# Show integration limits above & below the integral

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Well considering this code, the "E" is shown after the integral:

```
\begin{equation}
m = \iiint_E \rho \ \mathrm{d}V
\end{equation}
```

The limit is shown slightly behind the number, how can I place it in the middle below the triple integral?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to insert `\limits` after `\iiiint`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \iiint macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
m = \iiint\limits_E \rho \, \mathrm{d}V
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I ask why you put the comma between the rho and the integrant? - I added the extra backslash to add a space.

Comment: @paul23 - Actually, I didn't put in a comma, `,`; instead, I put in the `\,` *macro*, which inserts a typographic thinspace. In contrast, the `\ ` macro in your example inserts a full interword space, which is probably more whitespace than is typographically optimal.

Comment: I have an old, how-to-typeset-math, book from the 60s.  It's British (Oxford), and recommends a thickspace in that place.  (It also recommends placing the limits above and below the integral sign, even for single integral signs.) In American sources, I can only recall ever seeing thinspace recommended.

Comment: @dedded - In TeX's math mode, a typographic *thickspace* may be generated via either `\;` or `\thickspace`. The default values of thin-, med-, and thickspace, in both plain TeX and the LaTeX kernel, are `3mu`, `4mu`, and `5mu`, respectively. (Recall that `1em=18mu`. "Why `18mu` to the `em`?", you may ask. I have no idea...) The difference between thin- and thickspace thus isn't that huge -- though certainly noticeable to the human eye.

Comment: I thought an inter-word space was 0.25em (unstretched, of course), or 4.5mu, or about a thickspace. I was just noting that there was at least one style guide that regarded this as "optimal". (The book is _The Printing of Mathematics_ by T.W.Chaundy; rule 30b.) Like you, I use a thinspace, probably just because that's what I was taught to do.